# Generate data from the results of .describe() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I don't have access to the actual dataset, but I do have access to the results of the dataframes' `.describe()`. I need to construct some data that has similar statistics. Is there a way to generate random data that matches those statistics? ie I would ideally like a `data_generator(pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame` such that

```
data_gen(df.describe()).describe() == df.describe()
```

I understand that it won't capture the dependencies between columns but I will work with what I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50628583/18571565), you can create a dataframe `out_df` based on the characteristics of `df` - although not the quartiles.  The higher the number of data points (count), the closer the distributions of columns will match.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats

def my_distribution(min_val, max_val, mean, std):
    scale = max_val - min_val
    location = min_val
    # Mean and standard deviation of the unscaled beta distribution
    unscaled_mean = (mean - min_val) / scale
    unscaled_var = (std / scale) ** 2
    # Computation of alpha and beta can be derived from mean and variance formulas
    t = unscaled_mean / (1 - unscaled_mean)
    beta = ((t / unscaled_var) - (t * t) - (2 * t) - 1) / ((t * t * t) + (3 * t * t) + (3 * t) + 1)
    alpha = beta * t
    # Not all parameters may produce a valid distribution
    if alpha <= 0 or beta <= 0:
        raise ValueError('Cannot create distribution for the given parameters.')
    # Make scaled beta distribution with computed parameters
    return scipy.stats.beta(alpha, beta, scale=scale, loc=location)

desc = df.describe()
out_df = pd.DataFrame()
for col in desc.columns:
    data = my_distribution(desc.loc["min", col],
                           desc.loc["max", col],
                           desc.loc["mean", col],
                           desc.loc["std", col]).rvs(int(desc.loc["count", col]))
    out_df[col] = data

out_df.describe().sub(desc)
```