# How to best get a sample from a truncated normal distribution?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have done some searching but I cannot seem to be able to find a reasonable way to sample from a truncated normal distribution.

Without truncation I was doing:

```py
samples = [np.random.normal(loc=x,scale=d) for (x,d) in zip(X,D)]
```

`X` and `D` being lists of floats.

Currently I am implementing truncation as such:

```py
def truncnorm(loc,scale,bounds):
  s = np.random.normal(loc,scale)
  if s > bounds[1]:
    return bounds[1]
  elif s < bounds[0]:
    return bounds[0]
  return s

samples = [truncnorm(loc=x,scale=d,bounds=b) for (x,d,b) in zip(X,D,bounds)]
```

`bounds` being a list of tuples `(min,max)`

This approach feels a little awkward, so I'm wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: Well, what you've shown there isn't what is usually called a truncated normal distribution. Instead it's a mixture of a truncated normal with a discrete distribution which has a point mass at bounds[0] and another at bounds[1]. To get a truncated normal, you want `if s > bounds[1]: return truncnorm(loc, scale, bounds)` i.e., if you fall outside, try again. Depending on the bounds, you might have to try many times. If the majority of the mass is between the bounds, trying again is OK. But if the bounds might exclude most of the mass, you might want a different approach.

Comment: A different approach would be to invert the cdf, the cdf being a scaled version of the untruncated cdf (the scaling factor being equal to the mass between the bounds). That's going to be some expression involving erf. I don't know if inverse erf is among the functions available in numpy/scipy, but if not, you can invert it via bisection or something simple like that.

Comment: Have you seen [`scipy.stats.truncnorm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html)?  It isn't exactly the same as what you implemented, because (as @RobertDodier pointed out), your distribution has point masses at the bounds.  The usual [truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) doesn't have those point masses at the bounds.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I looked at the scipy function but I couldn't figure out how to set the range.

Comment: Dupe of [Python: Random number generator with mean and Standard Deviation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27831923/1782792)?

Comment: @JohanC I'm not sure what I am missing here but when getting a value from the distribution it frequently is outide the range `a->b` please see; https://repl.it/join/bqjdwnqq-jonathanwoollet

Comment: @JohanC So that seems to work. Maybe add a little extra explanation, put that as the answer and I'll mark it right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Returning the value of the bounds for samples outside them, will result in too many samples falling on the bounds. This is not representative of the actual distribution. The values on the bounds need to be rejected and replaced by a new sample. Such code could be:

```py
def test_truncnorm(loc, scale, bounds):
    while True:
        s = np.random.normal(loc, scale)
        if bounds[0] <= s <= bounds[1]:
            break
    return s
```

This can be extremely slow given narrow bounds.
Scipy's [truncnorm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html) handles such cases more efficiently. A bit surprisingly, the bounds are expressed in function of the standard normal, so your call would be:

```py
s = scipy.stats.truncnorm.rvs((bounds[0]-loc)/scale, (bounds[1]-loc)/scale, loc=loc, scale=scale)
```

Note that scipy works much faster when making use of numpy's [vectorization and broadcasting](https://unidata.github.io/python-training/workshop/NumPy/numpy-broadcasting-and-vectorization/). And once you're used to the notation, it also looks simpler to write and read. All samples can be calculated in one go as:

```
X = np.array(X)
D = np.array(D)
bounds = np.array(bounds)
samples = scipy.stats.truncnorm.rvs((bounds[:, 0] - X) / D, (bounds[:, 1] - X) / D, loc=X, scale=D)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across another way to do this, not much different really, it just handles the scaling using the cdf of the exact distribution you're sampling from, and then does the sampling using the distribution's inverse cdf (called ppf in scipy).

One advantage of this over the other method is that the random sampling here comes from a numpy uniform distribution so if you are controlling your random number seed with numpy already you don't have to then also define a random number seed in scipy.

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dist = norm(loc=2, scale=5)
a = -1 # lower cutoff
b = 10 # upper cutoff

x = np.linspace(0,1,101)
x_scaled = x * (dist.cdf(b)-dist.cdf(a)) + dist.cdf(a)

plt.plot(x_scaled,dist.ppf(x_scaled))
```

[image: Plot of arbitrary section of inverse cdf]

Then to sample you do:

```
# you can follow the officially supported numpy rng method 
# here instead for random seed control
X = np.random.uniform(0,1,10000) * (dist.cdf(b)-dist.cdf(a)) + dist.cdf(a)
Y = dist.ppf(X)

plt.hist(Y)
```

[image: Histogram of samples]