# How would I generate 100000 random numbers using a normal distribution with a specified mean and standard deviation?

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from numpy.random import randn

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100000))
```

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The existing code as posted doesn't allow specification of the mean and standard deviation AFAIK.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831923/python-random-number-generator-with-mean-and-standard-deviation

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using e.g. `numpy`'s `random` subpackage.

```
import numpy as np

mean: float = 100.0
stdev: float = 3.0
n_samples: int = 100_000

samples: np.ndarray = np.random.normal(loc=mean,
                                       scale=stdev,
                                       size=n_samples)
```

Answer (score 1):

No third party packages needed, just the standard Python library:

```
import random
mu = 0.0
sigma = 10.0
for _ in range(100000):
    print(random.gauss(mu, sigma))
```

You could also use random.normalvariate instead of random.gauss.